# When should you start unit testing? (during which development stage?)

Tags: unit-testing, testing, debugging

I'm currently learning about unit testing, specifically JUnit (with Java).

Searching the web I see many threads talking about why you should use it, what type of methods you should use it with but I can't seem to find much information on **when** you should implement a unit test.

Is it best to incorporate it from the very beginning of a project and then with every method you create, you add a unit test? Or is it something that it's done towards the latter stages when the logic/structure of the program is closer to completion?

Comment: Don't listen to this railing academic (me), but: "_Unit tests are not a substitute for competence, and since most people write stupid test cases that can be compile-time or static-code checked anyway, their functionality is almost entirely duplicated by asserts and a debugger.   Unless you're writing safety-critical code, if you're a good programmer and have good design, unit tests are almost always wasted effort.  Even then, you should write test cases for modules on real data, not for CS 101 errors that can be found by your compiler._" **[back to reality; pray continue]**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should write your unit tests very near to when you write your code. "Timely" is one of the five core tenets of unit testing per *Clean Code*. There's even an approach that advocates writing your unit tests *before* your code. It's called Test Driven or Test First Development, depending on who you're talking to.

In my experience, it doesn't matter too much if the tests are done first or second, as long as the tests are done before the work as a whole is considered "done". This means having the unit tests *done* to consider your story/task done.

Doing the tests near the time you do your code lets you:

- Write better tests since you remember better what the code should be doing. And you remember how the code does it, making bugs quicker to fix once your unit tests find them.
- Catch bugs earlier, before others use your code. Catching bugs earlier means they're cheaper to fix.
- Not fall into the "oh, I'll do it later" trap.

Comment: `"oh, I'll do it later" trap` I'm very guilty of that! Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: I'd say it's even more pernicious than "I'll do it later".  You really *should* do them first, because when you do them last, you might *code* a unit test or two, but there's no way it'll be as good of a set of unit tests as if you did it up front.  When you do it *after* you've written the functional code, you always have in the back of your mind something like "This is a waste of time, I already KNOW this code works inside the real app!"  So you don't code them very well -- you're complying with the letter of the law, but not the spirit of good unit testing.

Comment: @JoeRounceville - Not in my experience. I mean, that does happen, but so does the "write test, write code to make that test work and some other code to make that code work, but no test for the other code" scenario. Having the discipline to make good tests is non-trivial in either scenario.

Comment: I don't follow your example--"write test, write code to make that test work ... for the other code". You don't write functional code that doesn't have a unit test first. It's a discipline that just becomes a habit. If it's not a habit yet, just say "I haven't developed that habit yet." There's no shame in it -- it takes time for it to become a habit. Test-first is based on the psychology that if we don't know exactly what we're expecting yet, we test better. It's the same reason functional testers find bugs in our "done" code--their expectations are fuzzier.

Comment: "For Agile development shops, this means having the unit tests done during your sprint.": As far as I know, Kanban does not have sprints. I think it would be more precise to say that you have to have your unit tests done before you consider the implementation of some functionality done.

Comment: @Giorgio - good point. Updated.

Comment: @Telastyn: super. +1.

Comment: I have found that it's best to mix TDD with some test second "stuff". A lot of times it is better (to me) to write the test first then write the code, but that has to be balanced with a bit of real world need too. Sometimes it's just better to write the code first (as apposed to a huge mock object) then test to make sure it's doing what you think. What ever you do, I do agree that test writing needs to be done before you consider the "code" done. Just remember to test both positive and negative results.

Comment: Ideally you also need people who only write test code. People who only know the interface and the contract. The developer isn't necessarily the best person to accurately assess what the developer might have forgotten to test.

Comment: @TimSeguine - good luck finding enough competent people who would only write unit tests for a living, and good luck convincing management to pay them enough to get them (instead of cheaper alternatives).

Comment: @Telastyn I did say "ideally", but in all honesty there are plenty of companies that at least do integration testing this way. Software is a product. Companies of any size that produce products should have a department for quality control.

Comment: In the real world, you might also want to write a test when you find a bug. Write the test that breaks with the bug, then make the patch that makes the test pass. If you are in a hurry, as it may happen with broken code, you may fix first, write the test seeing the fixed bug afterwards. CVS can help you make sure you actually see the bug you have fixed.

Answer (score 4):

You can start unit testing as soon as you have a notion of a class you want to create.  The meaning of "unit" will depend on the programming language.  For example, suppose you want to create a function to parse roman numerals.  You might start with this unit test:

```
public class RomanTest {
  public void iEquals1() {
    assertEquals(1, Roman.toInteger("I"));
  }
}
```

Your test won't compile, because you haven't created the Roman class.  So you write:

```
public class Roman {
  public static toInteger(String s) {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Wow, your first test passed!

Comment: How much mockup code do you write while writing the tests?

Comment: As much as needed, but as little as possible.  You don't want tests for a calling unit to depend on complex behavior in a called unit.

Answer (score 1):

You should start writing your tests when you start writing your code.

The important part is that any code you write is *driven* by a unit-test; instead of stepping through the code manually, do it with a test. It doesn't take that much more work to write a test than it does to step through the code.

By writing a test to drive your newly written code, you essentially capture that work; if you manually test the code all that effort just dissipates into the ether. If in, say, six months you or another programmer breaks the code, that test will be there to save you from having to repeat the testing effort. This is how unit-tests protect against regressions!

Over time you will see the benefits of writing unit-tests. One example, you can refactor your code and the unit-tests will tell you if you broke anything.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [Test-Driven Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) method if I were you.

It's pretty straightforward, you unit test the method before they exist, run the test. They will fail. You will then fix them by making your methods work.

Answer (score 0):

Start early! Why wait?

Once your system is more complex than a simple "Hello, World!" application, you can start writing unit tests to ensure that what you've coded works correctly. If you use a tool like maven for your builds, you can have the tests run with every build so you should know pretty quickly if newly written code has issues with existing code.

Answer (score -4):

Forget the unit testing. Write and test yourself by being a user. deliberately try to break what you wrote even to the point of doing things you would never do but someone else might. This way you will discover things you could not foresee when writing unit tests. Your unit tests will, like your code make sense, but users are free from such restrictions. Bring in some users often to test as you go. Make sure your instructions are understandable by engaging with users, which unit testing cannot do. create a class or even a function, test it now! Don't move on until you are satisfied it is well done.

Comment: Your method can't automatically find regressions for example. If you have automated tests for every bug you fix, then you can say with certainty that those bugs aren't in your program. Other bugs *will* be, but not those ones. You also have much less assurance that when you refactor you didn't break something.